# Update and access value from async function in javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, axios, promise

I'm trying to wrtie an async function that will print a dad joke in the console when i click the button.

```
const btn = document.querySelector("button");
const getDadJoke = async () => {
    const config = { headers: { Accept: "application/json" } }
    res = await axios.get("https://icanhazdadjoke.com", config
    );
    return res.data.joke;
}

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log(getDadJoke());
})
```

But It only prints out a promise in the console becasue I think async function always returns a promise object.

my question is How do I access the value returned from getDadJoke and `console.log` it.

I tried

```
const btn = document.querySelector("button");
let text = "orignal text"

const getDadJoke = async () => {
    const config = { headers: { Accept: "application/json" } }
    const res = await axios.get("https://icanhazdadjoke.com", config
    );
    text = res.data.joke;
}

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log(text)
})
```

but it only prints out "original text". (because getdadjoke was nvr called lol)

Comment: `await getDadJoke(); console.log( text );` - but you should **return** the `joke` from `getDadJoke` instead of mutating a global variable. Mutating shared state is bad.

Comment: You need to `await` the promise and then print it: `btn.addEventListener("click", async () => console.log(await getDadJoke()))`

Comment: …or just print the joke from inside `getDadJoke()`

Answer (score 0):

Since your `getDadJoke()` is an `async` function, I will always return a `Promise`. You should use `await` or `then()` to get the value from `Promise`.

Using **await**

```
btn.addEventListener("click", async () => {
    console.log(await getDadJoke());
})
```

or Using **then()**

```
btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    getDadJoke().then(joke => console.log(joke));
})
```